# Difference between Google Cloud Anchor and Microsoft Azure Spatial Anchor

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality, azure-spatial-anchors

I was looking at the documentation for uploading anchors and at first I started looking at Microsoft Azure Spatial Anchors. Then I came across the Google Cloud Anchor. I couldn't find any documentation mentioning the pros and cons of both libraries.

On an abstract level, I think that both libraries function the similar way to upload the anchors along with the features to a cloud service and be able to retrieve them by a uniqueId.

Is there any difference between them? Which is better?

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Anchors is built-in to the ARCore library. If you're already using ARCore for Android, adding it is pretty straight-forward. That said, the docs recommend that the user scan for 10 seconds (around an object of interest), so you probably want to change the UI / onboarding for the user.  The biggest limitation, is that the Cloud Anchors are only saved for 24 hours.

Azure Spatial Anchors do not have the 24 hour limitation. Their docs are pretty bare-bones. No API documentation or anything, but it looks pretty straight-forward based on their sample app and allows for either java(kotlin) or the NDK.

Comment: Isn't there a similar method such as "getRecommendedForCreateProgress" provided by azure? And why the 24 hr limit?

Comment: 24 hr limit is on Google's end. They're planning to drop the limit. See here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/call-for-collaborators#persistent_cloud_anchors

Comment: Also, seems like Azure's docs have improved by quite a lot. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/